# Run simple Javascript Scratch in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Tags: javascript, npm, intellij-idea

I would like to run and debug a simple (plain) Javascript I created over the `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Insert` shortcut in my IntelliJ Idea Ultimate.

I'd like to prevent to have to implement any boilerplate like a HTML file or npm project.

What is the easiest way to do it? Am I just overlooking any obvious feature?

I searched for a run feature similar to the Java launch configuration and tried it over a plain node project using `npm init --yes` and `npm run` in the same folder, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally all you need is right-clicking your JavaScript scratch file and choosing **Run**:

[image]

But you have to make sure that **Node.js** plugin is enabled in IDEA, and the local Node.js interpreter is installed and configured in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js**

Comment: Thank you! I did indeed disable the Node.js plugin and forgot about it..
Cheers

Comment: I also needed to activate the 'Node.js Remote Interpreter' plugin to make it work.

Comment: Good reminder to check that. I had disabled the JavaScript Debugger plugin, which also disabled the Node.js plugin too and I didn't notice that part

Answer (score 0):

If you have node installed locally you can simple run `node example.js`
and it should output into the terminal.